# Conditionally Limiting Related Resource Data in TastyPie

Tags: django, tastypie

I am new to Tastypie (and Django) and am running into a problem with circular many-to-many relationships in my app's api.

I have 3 models `RiderProfile`, `Ride`, and `RideMemebership`. `RiderProfilea` can belong to multiple `Rides`, and `Rides` can have multiple `RiderProfile`. The many-to-many relationship is mediated by `RideMembership`. My models look like:

```
class RiderProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    age = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
    rides = models.ManyToManyField('riderapp.Ride', through="RideMembership")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.get_username()


class Ride(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    riders = models.ManyToManyField(RiderProfile, through="RideMembership")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class RideMembership(models.Model):
    rider = models.ForeignKey(RiderProfile)
    ride = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.rider.user.get_username() + ' to ' + self.ride.name()
```

My TastyPie resources look like:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    ...

class RideResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Ride.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rides'

    riders = fields.ToManyField('riderapp.api.RiderProfileResource', 'riders', full=True)

class RiderProfileResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = RiderProfile.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'riders'

    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', full=True)
    rides = fields.ToManyField('riderapp.api.RideResource', 'rides', full=True)
```

When I GET either a `RiderProfile` or `Ride` (list or detail), I get a recursion error because the models are fetching themselves infinitely. I have tried using the `RelationalField.use_in` parameter, which is very close to what I am trying to accomplish - as it prevents a field from being included based whether the request is for a list or a detail. However, I am trying to remove a resource field based on which endpoint is called.

For instance, a request for `/rides`: 
I would like to have a list of all the `RiderProfile` items involved, but without their `Ride` list.

Likewise, a request for `/riders`:
I would like to have a list of all the `Ride` items for the `RiderProfile`, but without their `Rider` list.

What is the recommended solution for this? I have been playing the with the `dehyrdate` cycle, but am struggling to modify the set of related resources. I have also read answers about using multiple ModelResources for Rides and Riders. Is there a recommended way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for your advice!

**Update**

I added extra `ModelResources` for use with each endpoint (`RiderProfileForRideResource` and `RideForRiderProfileResource`), and it is working. I am just not sure this is the best approach. It creates additional endpoints that I don't really want to expose. Any thoughts on a better way?

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    ...

class RideResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Ride.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rides'

    riders = fields.ToManyField('riderapp.api.RiderProfileForRideResource', 'riders', full=True)

class RideForRiderProfileResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Ride.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rides_for_riders'

class RiderProfileResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = RiderProfile.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'riders'

    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', full=True)
    rides = fields.ToManyField('riderapp.api.RideForRiderProfileResource', 'rides', full=True)

class RiderProfileForRideResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = RiderProfile.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'riders_for_ride'

    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', full=True)

class RideMembershipResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = RideMembership.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rider_membership'
```

Comment: I don't think you should specify the m2m relationships on both models that relate to each other. Should only be by the "owning" side.

Comment: Ok, I may be doing something atypical. I am pretty new to this stuff :) I do, however, want to represent the relationship on both resources though. Is there a more proper way to structure my models/resources that will still allow me to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the cleanest one way to do it but you could try to remove *riders* or *rides* in the dehydrate cycle by checking the resource uri path of the api call you have made

```
    class RideResource(ModelResource):
       class Meta:
           queryset = Ride.objects.all()
           resource_name = 'rides'

       riders = fields.ToManyField('riderapp.api.RiderProfileResource', 'riders', full=True)

       def dehydrate(self, bundle):
            # You make api call to 'riders' and are dehydrating related source RideResource. Path should be of the form API/app_name/riders
            # When call made directly to this resource then uri path will be API/app_name/rides and if statement will not be entered
            if 'riders' in bundle.request.path:
                  del bundle.data['riders']
```

and vice versa for the opposite relation.

Comment: I tried this, but it still results in the recursion error. I assume the related field queries run before the dehydrate occurs. Thanks though. The request path checking is a neat approach. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a callable for the use_in attribute of your resource field instead of overriding dehydrate.

```
def riders_check(bundle):
    return 'riders' in bundle.request.path
```

Something like,

```
riders = fields.ToManyField('riderapp.api.RiderProfileForRideResource', 'riders', full=True, use_in=riders_check)
```